# Placeholder Text in NSTextfield bound to NSMutableString

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nstextfield

I have some NSTextfields that I put placeholder strings in via the cocoa gui builder.  Now that I used cocoa binding to link each field to its own nsmutablestring they all start out black.  I tried initializing the string's to nil, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you specify a default value in the bindings detail pane?

Comment: sorry I'm new to cocoa/objective-c.   I'm using Xcode 4.2, I when I look at the binding panel for the nstextfield I don't see a spot to enter a default value.  Am I missing something or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: I didn't phrase my comment very well.  Did you try setting a null value placeholder for your binding?

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that existing.  Thank you that was the problem. If you want to put that as an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a string value, setting the *null value placeholder* will work when bindings are in use.